# What is the meaning of Error Runtime exception at 0x00400048: store address not aligned on word boundary 0x1001003 in assembly language programming?

Tags: assembly, mips

I am learning assembly language programming this semester, and I have a very hard time with debugging in general. 
In this program, I am asking the user to enter an array size and then I simply store user-entered integer values in every cell of the array. I know that a word is 4 bytes but I can't figure out what is the problem here
Thanks

```
    .data 
str: .asciiz "Please enter the length of the array: "
str2: .asciiz "Please enter number: "
myarray: .space 12 

.text 
la $a0, str
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall

addi $t0, $v0, 0
addi $t1, $zero, 0

#bnez $t0, end
bne $t0, $t1, loop

loop:
la $a0, str2
li $v0, 4
syscall 
li $v0, 5
syscall
addi $s1, $v0, 0
sb $s1, myarray($t1) <-error here
addi $t1, $t1, 4
```

Comment: As the error says, your `myarray` is not word aligned. Align it with the proper directive or put it before your strings as `.data` is likely aligned.

Comment: Thank you for replying - should I remove the ".space" then?

Comment: The .space directive operates in terms of bytes, and hence doesn't automatically align (the .word directive does automatically align, but of course, you'd need 3 of those to make 12 bytes worth).

Comment: You still need to allocate the space.

Comment: I understood thank you very much

Comment: @Jester How can I do both: allocate space and align at the same time? Can I mention "myarrray" twice in the .data section?

Comment: As I said, just move that line up to before the strings. Or you could stick an alignment directive before  it. You did not say what assembler you use, but consult its manual.